# javascript function synchronization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this :

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //BLOCK1
    function startingFunction() {
        //do a server call, receive the response through callback functions, either successFunction or failFunction

        onSuccess : successFunction,
        onFailure : failFunction
    }

    function successFunction(result) {
        //called receiving the server response
        //configure something based on success
    }

    function failFunction(result) {
        //called receiving the server response
        //configure something based on failure
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // BLOCK2
    //javascript code that needs to wait for the result of the configuration made above in BLOCK1 in order to continue doing more stuff
</script>

<body>...</body>
</html>
```

How can i make the javascript code in BLOCK2 to wait until the server has responded something and the configuration has been made?

Comment: Why not use the ol' trusty `$( document ).ready(function() {` ?  There's a jQuery tag on this question after all

Comment: assuming jquery ? not a good assumption.

Comment: @Abhishek Not an assumption, question tagged as such

Comment: Do you mean from an AJAX request or when the page has fully loaded?

Comment: oops. i misspoke. Perhaps that tag should be removed. There is nothing specific to jquery in this question.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter, because they are not wanting to do something on DOM readiness, but after some server call (ajax) has finished. Probably after successFunction has executed: _"make the javascript code in BLOCK2 to wait until the server has responded"_

Comment: @PatrickEvans Maybe, but my hunch based on the question wording is that $( document ).ready(function() { would accomplish what OP wants to do.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter, none of the wording suggests needing to use the DOM: _"//do a server call, receive the response through callback functions"_, _"//javascript code that needs to wait for the result of the configuration made above in BLOCK1"_, _"//called receiving the server response"_ all of these suggest OP is using some ajax call, none mention DOM or an element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply call a function in your second block from both functions that could be called in the first block. (assuming you want to continue after a failure)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //BLOCK1
    function startingFunction() {
        //do a server call, receive the response through callback functions, either successFunction or failFunction

        onSuccess : successFunction,
        onFailure : failFunction
    }

    function successFunction(result) {
        //called receiving the server response
        //configure something based on success
        afterConfiguration();
    }

    function failFunction(result) {
        //called receiving the server response
        //configure something based on failure
        afterConfiguration();
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // BLOCK2
    //javascript code that needs to wait for the result of the configuration made above in BLOCK1 in order to continue doing more stuff

    function afterConfiguration(){
      //code that needed to wait
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place the code in block two inside a function, then invoke that function at the end of `successFunction`.

Then again, I don't see the point of splitting this up in two `script` elements.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a flag and check periodcally using setInterval():

### Using a Flag:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
//BLOCK1
var block1Success = false; // <-- this is our flag
function startingFunction() {
    //do a server call, receive the response through callback functions, either successFunction or failFunction

    onSuccess : successFunction,
    onFailure : failFunction
}

function successFunction(result) {
    //called receiving the server response
    //configure something based on success
    block1Success = true; // <-- flag is set here
}

function failFunction(result) {
    //called receiving the server response
    //configure something based on failure
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// BLOCK2
//javascript code that needs to wait for the result of the configuration      made above in BLOCK1 in order to continue doing more stuff
window.setInterval(
    function(){
       if(block1Success){ 
         // code need to be executed here..
         alert("block1 success executed");
       }
    }, 100)
</script>

<body>...</body>
</html>
```